# Per-site meta notifications don't ask you to see your profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, per-site-meta, stack-exchange-button

The notifications panel of the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ likes to give you an opportunity to bask in the glow of a new badge by providing a direct link to your profile on the relevant site.

However, this doesn't seem to happen for per-site metas:

[image: notification panel with normal and meta badge notifications]

I don't often click through anyway, but I can't think of any particular reason why the per-site meta notifications shouldn't have a link to your meta profile...so they should, for consistency.

Comment: How do you earn Mortarboard on a per-site meta? You don't earn reputation... Is it tracked silently or something?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. The system still records votes on posts and those influence badges accordingly.

Comment: Yep certainly a bug, per site meta does have its own set of badges and its own profile page.