# Yearling badge(s) not showing on Area 51

Tags: support, badges, area-51, notifications

I received a notification tonight that I had earned Yearling on Area 51:

[image: Notification]

However, it's not showing on my Area 51 page:

[image: Area51 badges]

It also doesn't appear in my network profile, so it's not a problem with the display in Area 51:

[image: Network profile]

What's up with this? Do I have an invisible badge, or did I receive an erroneous notification?

(And by the way, if the badge is supposed to be there, shouldn't I have two of them? I've had over 200 reputation points there for rather a while, so either I had it on my first anniversary, or I should have gained the badge when I got it after that.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You earned the Yearling badge on the Area 51 Discussion site, where it [does indeed appear on your profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28610/monica-cellio?tab=badges).

Usually there'd be a link with the notification that would have taken you to the right profile, but it seems to be absent for Area 51 Discussion site badge notifications in a similar way that the profile links for [per-site meta notifications are AWOL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136365/per-site-meta-notifications-dont-ask-you-to-see-your-profile).

Comment: Nope, it's a bit misleading. I checked your [network profile activity](http://stackexchange.com/users/505925/monica-cellio?tab=activity), which does have a link to the relevant badge page.

Comment: From experience, the link is always absent from per-site Meta notifications (a tad annoying sometimes).