# Discrepancies between Discussion and Main User on Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, profile-page

There a ton of discrepancies between my [discussion user profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78192/troniczomb) and my [main user profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/78192/) on Area 51.

The Discussion user page states I have 2 profile views, 2 badges, visited 10 days, and been a member for 3 months (at the time of writing this).

The Main user page states I have 5 profile views, 4 badges, visited 32 days, and been a member for 2 months (at the time of writing this).

Is this by design or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design. Statistics are captured independently for Area 51 proper and the Discussion site, and each site additionally has its own distinct set of badges <sup>[[1](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges)], [[2](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/badges)]</sup> (which sometimes [causes confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158846/yearling-badges-not-showing-on-area-51)).

Comment: Thanks! I had never realized there was any difference.