# Post notices broken on questions with old-style "automatically inserted text" duplicate banners

Tags: bug, design, duplicate-questions

We still have some duplicates around that [use auto-inserted markdown to create a duplicate banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336071/200582). The rendering of these duplicates is broken as of the [post notice redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/200582).

For instance, consider [What is the difference in python attributes with underscore in front and back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14671487/1709587).

[Via the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190803115506/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671487/what-is-the-difference-in-python-attributes-with-underscore-in-front-and-back), we can see that it looked fine in August:

[image: Screenshot]

But now, it has two banners, the top one of which is nonsensical:

[image: screenshot]

*Something* should be done to fix these - either tweaking the redesign to support them, or reopening and re-closing all those questions as has been suggested a few times in the past.